# .NET 5 Blazor Server ServiceStack template

Tags: .net, servicestack, asp.net-core-5.0, .net-5

I'm looking to build a .NET 5.0 Blazor Server app from scratch.  Rather than using the standard `blazorserver` template out of the box I would like to base the app on a ServiceStack API backend.

I see from the ServiceStack [templates-blazor](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-blazor) docs that the ServiceStack community has created a [.NET 5.0 Blazor WASM Template](https://github.com/nukedbit/blazor-wasm-servicestack).

I was wondering if there were any plans to create a similar template but for .NET 5.0 Blazor Server ?

Or alternatively how easy would it be to convert the [.NET 5.0 Blazor WASM Template](https://github.com/nukedbit/blazor-wasm-servicestack) for Blazor Server ?

Comment: There's currently no plans to provide an official Blazor Server template, you can try raising an issue with the [community Blazor template author](https://github.com/nukedbit/blazor-wasm-servicestack) to see if he's considering it, otherwise you can submit a [feature request on UserVoice](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/) so we can measure interest.